# Expanding to all in Xcode Projects groups

Tags: macos, xcode, tree-view

In Windows, when you start explorer, there will be a tree view on left side. After selecting a specific folder / drive when you press *, it will expand all to depth.

I want to do the same in Xcode - after selecting a particular group in Xcode Project, I want to fully expand it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Mac OS X equivalent for expanding a complete tree view is:

<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

Condensing it all is:

<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

Using Left and Right arrow on their own will only do it for the selected directory and not any child directories.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer by Chealion, you can also option-klik to fully expand or contract subtrees. 
The same as in the Mac Finder, basically.

Comment: It didn't work for me.